# Java & MySQL: Store an Read a 365 position of bitarray. HOW?

Tags: java, mysql, blob, bitset, bitarray

I am currently working with Java and MySQL, and I found an issue I don't know how to solve.

I have a class that stores a String of 365 positions that represents a Binary String "010111010010100...", and I would like to be able to store and read that field from the database.
Once it is read, I will perform an AND Logic operation with another bitarray.

I read about the BitSet class, that allows the logical operators (AND, OR, XOR, ...) between them. I tried it, but I didn't like the solutions I got. I could also try to transform the String to a byte array, and then store and read it from the database, in order to later perform the logic AND operation, but not sure if I would need to always create a BitSet, and how performant could it be.

I don't know which is the most performant way to do what I want:

- Convert the Binary String in another element.
- Store that element in the database (in the case of BitSet I tried to define the Database field as BLOB, but I had a lot of issues transforming the BitSet to BLOB and reading the BLOB to a BitSet).
- Read the element from the database (at this point would be great to directly work with the element without making any cast or transformation).
- Perform a logic AND with another bitarray and get the result.

I have tried a lot of options, but they didn't work.

Could someone help me with this problem and how to better approach it from the performance point of view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Storing bit in a string is bit weird, I used long to store a number, and make bitwise operations on that. It won't work for you, since you use much more bits. If it can remain string, maybe you can write a short function to make the AND operator on each byte of the string, somehow like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i<366; i++) {
    data .= (stringname[i] == binarystring[i]?"1":"0"); 
}
```

Go through your string, while checking if it equals binary string (The one you want to AND it), if they equal, concat 1, if not, concat 0;

Comment: Well, my first point was that I have to convert that String in another type. The problem is that it is 365 bits long, and I cannot be stored in one Long, so it has to be stored as a different way,...

Comment: Then put it into a byte or something array?

for (int i = 0; i<366/8;i+8) {
   for (int j=0;j<8;j++)
   (string[i+j] == "1"?byte[j] |= 0x01:byte[j ]|= 0x00 );
   byte[j] <<=1;
}

Or something similar.